# Best way to deal with a change in file formatting when parsing with Python?

Tags: python, parsing

I am working with a few thousand IRS 990 files in JSON, between 2013 and 2020. The specific element I'm trying to access is the tax year. From 2020 to 2014 the element is named `TaxYr` but prior to 2013 it is named `TaxYear`.

I am trying to basically go through all of the files and print the tax year, but at a certain point a reach an error due to the change in formatting.

There is no definitive line between the old and new format so I can't do this by year.

Here's the code I'm currently using:

```
i=0
while i <8326:
    with open("/Users/----/Desktop/all 990 JSON/allDAFs{}.json".format(i)) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    print(data["Return"]["ReturnHeader"]["TaxYr”])
    i=i+1
```

If anybody has any suggestions please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would have to debug it, I will try first:

```
for i in range(8326):
    with open("/Users/----/Desktop/all 990 JSON/allDAFs{}.json".format(i)) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    try:
        print(data["Return"]["ReturnHeader"]["TaxYr"])

    except KeyError: 
        print("The Json format changed in: ", i)
        print(data)
        break
```

Than, I would see how th format is in the rest of the files and let's say it would have the field `data["Return"]["ReturnHeader"]["TaxYear"]`

I would just add:

```
 for i in range(8326):
    with open("/Users/----/Desktop/all 990 JSON/allDAFs{}.json".format(i)) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    if i < index_found:
        print(data["Return"]["ReturnHeader"]["TaxYr"])
    else:
        print(data["Return"]["ReturnHeader"]["TaxYear"])
```

---

**Edit**

I would try something like this:

```
 for i in range(8326):
    with open("/Users/----/Desktop/all 990 JSON/allDAFs{}.json".format(i)) as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    if all(["Return" in data, "ReturnHeader" in data["Return"], "TaxYr" in data["Return"]["ReturnHeader"]):
        print(data["Return"]["ReturnHeader"]["TaxYr"])
    elif all(["Return" in data, "ReturnHeader" in data["Return"], "TaxYear" in data["Return"]["ReturnHeader"])::
        print(data["Return"]["ReturnHeader"]["TaxYear"])
    else:
        print(data)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. Unfortunately there is no single point where it goes from `TaxYr` to `TaxYear` so for example i = 6300 and 6302 could be `TaxYr` but 6301 could be `TaxYear` so this solution doesn't really work. If you have any other ideas please let me know.

Comment: I guess, that there is a final amount of schemes. So you can ind them out in the way I showed you. After you will found out, you can check if the key exists.I edited my answer, after a few iteration you should finish